# How can I get the height and width values of View's text size in pixels?

Tags: java, android, text, view, text-size

I need to get height and width of the textView's text.
Yes there is a method called textView.getTextSize(), but I don't understand what that size means: a height, a width or something else? I need the exact width and height values (it will be good, if values will be in pixels not sp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be with the use of [`getPaint()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getPaint()) and [`getTextBound()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect))

```
String text = (String) textView.getText();
Rect textBound = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),textBound);
int textHeight = textBound.height();
int textWidth = textBound.width();
```

I am not entirely sure of the height and width being in pixel. Based on this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540253/rectf-use-dp-or-px) in regards to `RectF`, I believe `Rect` as well should use pixels.

Comment: Interesting experiment: I tried to get values with Log.d(), the first value is the height, which I tried to get with the code, you wrote and the second value is the same height but this time by textView.getTextSize(). I think that textView.getTextSize() returns value of height, cause another person who answered, said that. But the strange thing is: that two returned values are not the same. the first == 31 and the second == 39.0. I read the docs and there is said that textView.getTextSize() returns value in pixels. The same thing is written for Rect. So what's going on? O_O

Comment: The difference seem to be similar to the difference between `measureText()` and `getTextBound()` width as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds/7579469#7579469).

Answer (score 0):

`getTextSize()` returns the `TextView`'s line height in pixels.

I think what you're looking for is `textView.getLayout().getHeight()` and `textView.getLayout().getWidth()`, although the `Layout` can be null if the TextView changed recently.

Comment: for the "getTextSize() returns the TextView's height in pixels." thanks. That's a great info. But the other part you misunderstood. No I don't need the values of the View, I need only values of the text of the View. Only that.

Answer (score 0):

`getTextSize()` returns the size of the text set on the which is effectively the font size of the `TextView`, you can determine this by looking at the `setTextSize` method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize(int,%20float)

To figure out the height/width of a TextView you could use:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getMeasuredHeight()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getMeasuredWidth()

This is assuming that the view has been measured and laid out.

As for useful conversions that could be helpful here refer to:
[How to convert DP, PX, SP among each other, especially DP and SP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664993/how-to-convert-dp-px-sp-among-each-other-especially-dp-and-sp)

Whenever unsure about what a method does, check the docs and also check other methods to figure out what it does, like you can figure out what `getTextSize` returns by looking at `setTextSize`.